# how to convert php regex to java regex

Tags: java, php, regex

i am not good in regex, please help to convert php regex to java regex?

Php regex:

```
$c = preg_match_all("/gwtHash:\"(.*?)\"/", $page, $m);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Pattern` class.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("gwtHash:\"(.*?)\"");
```